# Is there any short cut to switch [find in selection] in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode and I press [option + f] in mac to search, and it will find in selection automatically even thouth i have set [never automatically find in selection]. So i want to use a short cut to switch it off. Is there any short cut or is there any way to set one?

[picture of the button in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prYyW.png)

Comment: I'm on my Linux machine right now, but when I hover that button with the cursor for a moment it eventually surfaces a tooltip showing the keyboard shortcut to toggle it (`Alt+L`).  I'd recommend doing the same on your system.

Comment: You can use `Alt+L` shortcut to switch it on and off

Comment: ok, I am on a mac and it works.  really thx. It helps a lot.
I get trapped in such a stupid problem, hahaha